# Poco::Data::Keywords::use not working for PostgreSQL?

Tags: poco-libraries

I'm trying to insert values in PostgreSQL with POCO. I'm trying to do it with Poco::Data::Keywords::use:

```
try
{
        Poco::Data::PostgreSQL::Connector::registerConnector();

        Poco::Data::Session session(Poco::Data::PostgreSQL::Connector::KEY,
                                    "host=localhost port=5433 user=test password=test dbname=test_db");

        int test1_id = 1;
        int test2_id = 2;
        int id = 0;

        session << "insert into test (test1_id, test2_id) values (?, ?) returning id",
                Poco::Data::Keywords::use(test1_id),
                Poco::Data::Keywords::use(test2_id),
                Poco::Data::Keywords::into(id),
                Poco::Data::Keywords::now;

        std::cout << "id = " << id << std::endl;
}
catch (const Poco::Exception& ex)
{
    std::cout << "exception: " << ex.displayText() << std::endl;
}
```

But I'm getting an exception:

```
exception: PostgreSQL: [PostgreSQL]: postgresql_stmt_prepare error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ... into test (test1_id, test2_id) values (?, ?) retur...
                                                             ^
 insert into test (test1_id, test2_id) values (?, ?) returning id
```

If I'm inserting other way:

```
session << "insert into presentation (test1_id, test2_id) values ('" 
    << test1_id << "', '" << test2_id << "') returning id",
    Poco::Data::Keywords::into(id),
    Poco::Data::Keywords::now;
```

It works fine. What am I doing wrong with first way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works

```
 session << "insert into test (test1_id, test2_id) values ($1, $2) returning id",
                Poco::Data::Keywords::use(test1_id),
                Poco::Data::Keywords::use(test2_id),
                Poco::Data::Keywords::into(id),
                Poco::Data::Keywords::now;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its crazy, POCO does not provide any guide for PostgreSQL placeholders.

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) the solution

Basically: use $<place_holder_index> instead of '?'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).